# setting up turtles with preset distance between them (netlogo)

Tags: netlogo

I am a high school student and I have to make a model about plants and plagues. I want to setup turtles with a preset distance from each other, but I can't figure out how to do that without creating an infinite loop. This is what my code looks like. Now it creates 20 turtles with random distance between them, but I want them to have a preset distance and as much turtles there can be on the screen with that distance between them.

```
to setup
  clear-all
  ask patches [ set pcolor 33 ]
  make
  repeat 20 [maken]
  reset-ticks
end

to make
 create-aardappelplanten 1[
   setxy random-xcor random-ycor
   set color green
   set size 1.5
   set shape "plant"
   set age 1
  ]
end
```

Thank you so much!!

Comment: The way you have worded this suggests that the turtle have to be exactly some distance from each other. In that case you can place the first one randomly and then place each of the others with `x-cor` and `y-cor` values that are the original turtle's values plus the distance change. Or do they have to be at least some distance apart?

Comment: Your goal is unclear.  Does putting one turtle at the center of each patch meet your need?  (You can change the number of rows and columns however you wish.)

Comment: You have two problems here: decide on a method for placing the turtles, and then actually write code that implements that method. For the decide-on-a-method part, it seems like a number of different approaches would be possible. Do you have an idea for it...?